# onPreferenceClick listener not working / onPreferenceClick not being called

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, onpreferenceclicklistener

I am trying to open a website when one of my preferences is clicked (not when the preference is actually changed because there isn't one).

The problem is that the `onPreferenceClick()` is never called.

This is my `PreferenceActivity`:

```
public class About extends PreferenceActivity implements
        OnPreferenceClickListener {

TextView tv_developer;
TextView tv_version;
String versionName;

int counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.about);        

        Preference p_developer = (Preference) findPreference("p_developer");
        p_developer.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);

        Preference p_licences = (Preference) findPreference("p_licences");
        p_licences.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference pref) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.i("Anything pressed", "YES");
        if (pref.getKey().equals("p_developer")) {
            Log.i("p_developer", "YES");


        } else {
            Log.i("p_developer", "NO");
        }
        return true;
    }   
}
```

This is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="about"
    android:title="About" >


    <Preference
        style="?android:preferenceInformationStyle"
        android:key="p_licences"
        android:title="p_licences" />

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Category" >

        <Preference
            style="?android:preferenceInformationStyle"
            android:key="p_developer"
            android:title="p_developer" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

I have also found that this does not do anything either:

```
<Preference android:title="@string/prefs_web_page" >
    <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:data="http://www.example.com" />
</Preference>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `android:enabled="true"` to `Preference`:

```
<Preference
    style="?android:preferenceInformationStyle"
    android:key="p2"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:title="p2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using:

```
 PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.about);
```

Shouldn't it be more like:

```
 PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.yourxmlfilename);
```

Since thae preferences you defined **are not a layout.**
You need to **load the name of the .xml file**, not the key of the preference in .xml.

So, **put your preferences .xml file in the "xml" folder**, and give it a name like "mypreferences.xml". Then, load it like that:

```
PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.mypreferences);
```

In my project, the file looks like this: **(name "settings.xml")**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Your Settings" >
            <Preference
            android:key="delete"
            android:title="Delete User"
            android:summary="Deletes the user." />

      <!-- and so on -->
```

I add it to the PreferenceActivity by calling:

```
PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
```

And **set the onClickListener:**

```
Preference deletePref = (Preference) findPreference("delete");
        deletePref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                // do stuff
                return true;
            }
        });
```

And it works.

Furthermore, you could try **using a different name for title and key.**

Comment: That didn't help - its basically what I've done already, my preferences were just in a defferent folder

Comment: See my updated answer. I posted the full code + xml file. This solution works fine in my project.

Comment: Have you tried using different names for key and title? Other than that, I really don't know. Please double check if you do it exactly as I posted above. It should work.

Comment: Just double checked everything - still no luck.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Fresh answer here.

You need to declare listener first. And then attach that listener for each(!) of end Preference objects. Like these:

```
    final static int CAMERA_SLEEP_TIME=0,
                CAMERA_TIME=1,
                RESET=2;

private Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener listener =new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        String keyLcl = preference.getKey();
       if(keyLcl.equals(cameraSleepTime))
           triggerPrefsDialog(CAMERA_SLEEP_TIME);
        else
       if (keyLcl.equals(cameraTime))
           triggerPrefsDialog(CAMERA_TIME);
        else
       if (keyLcl.equals(reset))
           triggerPrefsDialog(RESET);
        else
       return false;
        return true;

    }


};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    Resources resLcl = getResources();
    cameraSleepTime=resLcl.getString(R.string.camera_sleep_time);
    cameraTime=resLcl.getString(R.string.camera_time);
    reset =resLcl.getString(R.string.reset);
    PreferenceScreen sceenLcl = getPreferenceScreen();
    PreferenceCategory pcLcl=(PreferenceCategory)sceenLcl.getPreference(1);
    pcLcl.getPreference(0).setOnPreferenceClickListener(listener);
    pcLcl.getPreference(1).setOnPreferenceClickListener(listener);
    pcLcl=(PreferenceCategory)sceenLcl.getPreference(2);
    pcLcl.getPreference(0).setOnPreferenceClickListener(listener);
    l.a(pcLcl.getTitle());
}
```

And related preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceCategory

    android:title="@string/switch_mode">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="@string/enable_switch"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:title="@string/is_switched"

        />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory

    android:title="@string/seconds_category">
    <Preference
        android:key="@string/camera_time"

        android:defaultValue="600000"
        android:title="@string/camera_time"
        />
    <Preference
        android:key="@string/camera_sleep_time"
        android:defaultValue="600000"
        android:title="@string/camera_sleep_time"
        />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/System">
    <Preference
        android:key="@string/reset"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:title="@string/reset"
        />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/to_be_added">
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to extend the existing `PreferenceCategory` class (in Support Library) and override `isEnabled()`. This method always returned `false` so I created a class called `ClickablePreferenceCategory` and changed it to `true`.

In addition to that I had to add `android:selectable="true"` to my custom Preference xml node. The result looks like this:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:enabled="true"
    android:key="@string/key_category_problem_solving"
    android:selectable="true"
    android:title="@string/problem_solving">

</PreferenceCategory>
```

And the `ClickablePreferenceCategory`:

```
public class ClickablePreferenceCategory extends PreferenceCategory {

    public ClickablePreferenceCategory(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public ClickablePreferenceCategory(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public ClickablePreferenceCategory(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ClickablePreferenceCategory(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```